# Wood stain didn't take in some areas. Not sure how to proceed. What should I do next?

Tags: woodworking, stairs, stain, treads

I tried staining the treads on some stairs we had installed. And, for the most part, it looks really good. But, the stain didn't seem to take in a couple areas. Here is an image showing one example where the stain didn't take

[image: stain1]

For background, here was my procedure:

1. Sanding
2. Apply mineral spirits, wait for drying
3. Apply pre-stain
4. Apply stain, and wipe off excess stain

My guess was that there was some contamination in the area that didn't take stain and that I simply hadn't sanded enough through this. So, I sanded just that area and applied the stain again. But, this didn't seem to help much. Here is how it looks now

[image: stain2]

So, I have a couple questions, with the main one being: What should I do?

Some other thoughts/questions I have:

1. Is the problem with my "fix" that I should have also applied a pre stain again? Because, in the second picture it does seem like some of the stain took, but it clearly doesn't match with the original. So, maybe it's because I didn't use pre stain?
2. I clearly increased the "bad" area in size a bit with my sanding. I find it interesting that this new area all looks consistent with itself now (but not with the rest of the wood that originally took stain). I think this is perhaps consistent with the idea that I needed to apply the pre stain to this bad area to make it look consistent with the "good" parts?
3. In the second picture, the "good" part of the wood that has taken the stain looks a bit different from the first picture. Not sure if it's the lighting? Or does the stain change over a couple days?
4. Is it bad that I haven't applied polyurethane to the good areas yet? I was wanting to wait until the bad area looks good.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What was on it before?  It almost looks like some type of adhesive residue.

Comment: @crip659 I started with raw wood. So, nothing should have been on it. But, I suppose some glue may have found its way on the "bad" area when the stairs were constructed.